# Early stopping : neural networks

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I'm working on relation classification with the SemEval2010 Task 8 dataset. The dataset is already split into 8'000 samples for the training and 2'717 for the testing. In order to be as fair as possible, I use only my model at the end to computing its performance (F1-Score).

In order to tune my convolutional neural networks, I keep 6'400 samples for the training and 1'600 for the validation. I train the model and after each epoch (~10' of computation) I compute the F1-Score of my predictions.

I read the paper http://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/prechelt/Biblio/stop_tricks1997.pdf and stop training when the last 3 performances were increasing (similar to UP in the paper). In the paper, they return the model corresponding to the best performance seen so far.

My question is : in order to be as accurate as possible, we need the whole 8'000 samples for the training. Is it correct to say we will train until the epoch which had the best performance on the validation set and then do the predictions ? Or should we save the model corresponding to the best performance and "waste" 1'600 samples ?

Comment: Perform cross-validation on the whole training set (the 8.000 samples).

Comment: I don't do CV because it will cost me too much time but let's suppose I do CV and what next ? I can find the best parameters with CV. How do I know when I stop training on the whole dataset in order to do the predictions ?

Comment: You will continue to use the same UP approach but train using CV. If you don't perform CV you are "wasting" those 1600 samples. CV is the best way to make your training set as representative as possible.

Comment: I'm implementing this paper http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/P15-1061 and I have to found a way at which epoch to stop. With k-fold CV, you have to train k times your networks in order to find the best params on the average scores on the k validations sets (and also at which epoch to stop). My question is once I have found the best params, should I do the training on the whole training set and stop at the i'th epoch found before ?

Comment: The answer is not trivial because each fold may have different local minima. Your idea is valid, but you can try out different variations as well (a plot of the stops for each fold may prove useful if it remains the same more or less, or use it accordingly). Last but not least, you can find an optimal stoppage time by applying meta-optimization on the epochs by using genetic algorithms or PSO as a meta-optimizer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you have resources about applying genetic algorithms or PSO on the epochs ? (I know both algorithms)

Comment: You can have a look at this http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/pkoehn/publications/gann94.pdf which is fairly basic. If I were you, I would start with the basics: Encode the number of epochs as a binary string and run the GA then plot the accuracy of results.